# My Alarm I set up on my app didn't work on an actual device, the sound also didn't play on emulator

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, repeatingalarm

I set up an alarm in my app to ring at 6:00pm everyday and I ran it on my emulator, it worked, but not in real-time, and also the sound I set did not play. So I wanted to see how it really works on an actual phone. I downloaded it to an actual device (API 15) and the time I set up for the alarm came and nothing happened? I know my code is correct, because it worked on the emulator, but why won't it work on my device? And is anyone able to test if this works on their own device? Please?

This is my MyReceiver.java file

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    context.startService(service1);

}
}
```

This is my Alarm.java file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class Alarm extends Service {

NotificationManager nm;
Notification notify;
CharSequence from="Almost here!";
CharSequence message="Check out when!";



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    from="Almost here!";
    message="Check out when!";
    Uri path=Uri.parse("com.example.kn.b" + R.raw.bl);
    Intent intent1=new Intent(Alarm.this,NotificationPage.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(Alarm.this,1,intent1,0);
    Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(Alarm.this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle(from);
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ft);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setSound(path);
    builder.build();
    nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notify=builder.getNotification();
    notify.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(0, notify);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

This is the code snippet I put in my Main.java to set the time of the alarm

```
    today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent myIntent=new Intent(Main.this, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this,0,myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,today.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000,pendingIntent);
```

Please any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this actually work? Uri path=Uri.parse("com.example.kn.b" + R.raw.bl); How is that even a valid URI? Also please be specific about WHAT works and WHAT doesn't work. Your post is very ambiguous about the difference between the device/emulator.

Comment: yes, it is. I saw an example to parse the path to the raw folder and that is what I did. Also, I said the alarm worked on my emulator but not in real time, but the sound did not play. However, when I tried the app on an actual android device, the time came and passed, and the alarm did nothing. Sorry for the confusion.